# How do ActionMessages supports nternationalization in struts 2?

Tags: java, struts2

I want to read actionmessages from the property file in struts2 and at the same time I want to maintain internationalization in my application. How can I do that?

Comment: what you mean by want to maintain internationalization in my application same time?

Comment: maintain internationalization means like its easy to read from property file explicitly by resource bundle but than you have to explicitly handle the internationalization part... There must be some direct way in struts2

Comment: you have to explicitly handle the internationalization part what this means? S2 provides a very lean way to handle i18n

Comment: Have you read the [localization docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/localization.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getText("<property-name>")
```

This method in struts will pickout value from property file according to current locale of system or browser.
Just you have to take care of naming conventions of the property files.
Easy like eating a cake.. cheers :)